# What happened in Wall Street when Bud was asked to cover for his client's loss?

Tags: wall-street

In this movie, *Wall Street*, Bud Fox was having a conversation with his client, it goes something like:

> BUD: You are a gentleman, sure it is going down a bit, but
>
> UNKNOWN CLIENT: give it back (not very audible)
>
> BUD: give it to whom? you own it
>
> BUD'S BOSS shows up standing in front of him
>
> BUD: no, my boss is not here right now
>
> BUD'S BOSS wants the phone to talk to this client
>
> BUD'S BOSS: this is the sale's manager, what seems to be the problem?
>
> UNKNOWN CLIENT: I want him to pull my account (not very audible)
>
> BUD'S BOSS: I will discuss with the account executive.
>
> BUD'S BOSS gives the phone back to BUD
>
> BUD'S BOSS: I am closing the account, if he does not pay, you pay.
>
> BUD: Mr. Lynch, I swear to you, he is lying.
>
> BUD'S BOSS: I gave you one of the rich men's accounts, you tell me he is gonna DK for a lousy 1/4 point?
>
> BUD: I do not think it is fair, you assigned me this guy, you know he has got a history of ...
>
> BUD'S BOSS: somebody is gonna pay, it ain't to be me.

What is exactly the problem? Without much background knowledge, I do not understand this scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because that's not what they are saying. In your quote there are missing lines.

Howard, the client, made a bad decision and lost money. Bud try to explain that it was Howard decision so he shouldn't be responsible for it. Howard then lie to Bud boss about it and he make a decision that it have to be Bud who need to pay (in real money) for this.

You can read the script [Wall Street Script](http://www.actorpoint.com/movie-scripts/scripts/wall-street.html)

BTW. Bud have to pay 7K$ in one day. Around 15K in 2018 money.

Comment: Can Bud's boss make Bud do that? It does not sound very legal

Comment: There are more things in Wall Street that are not very legal. But yes, usually it is legal to debit worker for his personal mistakes that caused damage to company.